# Webpage is not rendering the same in IE9 live as it does locally

Tags: html, html-rendering

I have this webpage that looks fine on my local machine but as soon as I deploy this live it looses all its formating:

http://www.luc.edu/new/mba-dev/test/

I have made sure all the link references are absolute. Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening?

Firefox, Safari look fine live as well, its just IE but live, locally looks fine

Comment: It looks the same to me in Chrome and IE9.  If you use the F12 (Developer) tools in IE, does it look like all of the resources are loading correctly?  Do you have a local DNS override (e.g. hosts file) that might be messing you up?

Comment: are u saying that it has a background image and everything?

Comment: Yep.  Street sign, visible in Chrome and IE9.  I updated my first comment with more ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors in you code eg. on line 1300 you have `('#excerpt').find('p')` which should be `$('#excerpt').find('p')` also the pageslide js is not loading. Firefox and chrome seem to be a lot more error tolerant than ie, I also notice Ie has one mode for online and another for offlineI suggest using something like firebug when doing web development

Answer (score 1):

`http://www.luc.edu/new/mba-dev/test/js/jquery.pageslide.min.js` is a **404**.

> SEC7112: Script from
>   https://raw.github.com/ethagnawl/ellipsify/master/jquery.ellipsify.js
>   blocked becuase of MIME-match error

Says IE9. I suggest you to host this file on your server instead.

The page looks alright in IE9 but fails in IE7.